# Is it possible to create a scheduler on JFrog Xray?

Tags: jfrog-xray

Is it possible to create a scheduler on JFrog Xray that generates report at specified interval?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, it is not possible to have a scheduler in the JFrog Xray to generate reports, however, you can write a script on top of this Xray [generate report REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Xray+REST+API#XrayRESTAPI-REPORTS) and schedule this script to run based on the cronjob so it is automated.

PS: There are different REST APIs as mentioned in the wiki and you can select what report you need and run the relevant REST API accordingly.

Comment: Can we generate the reports dynamically by having scope of defined repos and builds using azuredevops pipeline? The API call Json is seems bit difficult to modified by the pipeline parameters or variables of repos and builds